# Hidden text Embedding

Tags: c#, text

I'm working on a proof of concept for hidden embedded information. Let me explain this a little. For example we want to add some hidden text to an HTML page in such a way that viewing the source of HTML page a normal human eye cannot detect if there is something added to it. Only a desktop application would be able to read the information using an algorithm.
We have some rough ideas but I would like if someone can point out any algorithm already available.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to do this using met tags. The information is encrypted and the encrypted code is added to a custom meta tag. The reversing algorithm will take that encrypted code and decrypt it.